# Rails 3 multi-part search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I've spent a few days on this and just haven't been able to get my head around how to apply a scope or other method to this. I've also tried some search gems but because I'm at such a basic level, wanted to keep things as simple as possible. The effort below is loosely based on rails casts #37 "simple search" tutorial. Its the only one that's been marginally successful.

My problem; I want to run a search on year, make, model, engine(if any), drilling down to the desired vehicle(s). To make things easy on me, I did one search per page. Currently I'm not able to carry the previous search params over to the current search. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this than the one below, and I'm open to suggestions. I just haven't been able to successfully adapt examples I've found online.

The Database:
I have a postgres database table named "carinfo", that table has columns "id, caryear, carmake, carmodel, carengine, submodel, website1, website2, website3". I've populated it with some test data with a dozen or so vehicles.

controllers/listing_controller.rb

To simplify things I haven't used a model yet so its all in the controller:

```
class ListingController < ApplicationController 
  include ListingHelper 

  def year 
    @searchyr = Carinfo.find(:all)
  end

  def make
    @searchmk = Carinfo.find(:all, :conditions => ['caryear LIKE ?', "%#{params[:year]}%"])
  end

  def model
    @searchmdl = Carinfo.find(:all, :conditions => ['caryear LIKE ? AND carmake LIKE ?', "%#{params[:year]}%", "%#{params[:make]}%"] )
      # '%2009%' static values work ok
  end

  def engine
    @searcheng = Carinfo.find(:all, :conditions => ['caryear LIKE ? AND carmake LIKE ? AND carmodel LIKE ?', "%#{params[:year]}%", "%#{params[:make]}%", "%#{params[:model]}%"])
  end

  def selectedcar
    @searchres = Carinfo.find(:all, :conditions => ['caryear LIKE ? AND carmake LIKE ? AND carmodel LIKE ? AND carengine LIKE ?', "%#{params[:year]}%", "%#{params[:make]}%", "%#{params[:model]}%","%#{params[:engine]}%"])
  end

end
```

views/listing/year.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Year") %> 
<h1>Year Search - Under: Listing</h1>

<%= form_tag(make_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= select_tag :year, options_for_select(@searchyr.collect{|y| [y.caryear, y.caryear]}.uniq), {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'} %>
<% end %>

<!-- this can be deleted once everything is working  it just helps see what's filtered -->
<ul>
    <% for search in @searchyr %>
    <li>
        <%= search.caryear %>
        <%= search.carmake %>
        <%= search.carmodel %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<center><%= button_to "Reset Search", year_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></center>
```

views/listing/make.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Make Search") %> 
<h1>Make Search - Under: Listing</h1>

<%= form_tag(model_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= select_tag :make, options_for_select(@searchmk.collect{|y| [y.carmake, y.carmake]}.uniq), {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'} %>
<% end %>

<center><%= button_to "Reset Search", year_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></center>
```

views/listing/model.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Model Search") %> 
<h1>Model Search - Under: Listing</h1>

<%= form_tag(engine_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= select_tag :model, options_for_select(@searchmdl.collect{|y| [y.carmodel, y.carmodel]}.uniq), {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'} %>
<% end %>

<center><%= button_to "Reset Search", year_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></center>
```

views/listing/model.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Engine Search") %> 
<h1>Engine Search - Under: Listing</h1>

<%= form_tag(selectedcar_path, :method => "get") do %>
    <%= select_tag :engine, options_for_select(@searcheng.collect{|y| [y.carengine, y.carengine]}.uniq), {:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'} %>
<% end %>

<center><%= button_to "Reset Search", year_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></center>
```

views/listing/selectedcar.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Selected Car") %> 
<h1>Selected Car - Under: Listing</h1>


<center><%= button_to "Reset Search", year_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></center>

<ul>
    <% for search in @searchres %>
    <li>
        <%= search.caryear %>
        <%= search.carmake %>
        <%= link_to search.carmodel, search_path(search) %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

config/routes.rb
Just the section dealing with this problem:

```
  match '/year',          to: 'listing#year'
  match '/make',          to: 'listing#make'
  match '/model',          to: 'listing#model'
  match '/engine',          to: 'listing#engine'
  match '/selectedcar',          to: 'listing#selectedcar'
```

As always, help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Mike

Comment: `To make things easy on me, I did one search per page.` <- it seems to me that this actually makes things much more complicated.

Comment: I guess I did it this way because the in my head it made it easier to display the current dropdown list filtered by the previous drop down as opposed to trying to filter sub-dropdowns on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're controller doesn't need all of those methods, do something like this:

```
class ListingController < ApplicationController 
  include ListingHelper 


  def search
    @search = Carinfo.where('caryear LIKE ?', params[:year]) unless params[:year].blank?
    @search = @search.where('carmake LIKE ?', params[:make]) unless params[:make].blank?
    etc etc...
  end

end
```

Then just have one form that has all of the inputs that you'd like to search

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm working on tying in the inputs but everything takes me a while to work through.

Comment: I've tried several different selects in the view and they either have a problem with 'each' or 'collect'. can you give me an example of a properly formatted select input? Thanks. Mike

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the selects on the search function, you should be posting to it. So your index method, or whatever it is that has your page on it, should have the options for your select. So if you want to search all makes, you'd have: `options_from_collection_for_select(@car_makes, 'id', 'make')` You can read up on select stuff here: [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)